# how to send the error message of a result query to the UI instead of displaying in console in nodejs and expressjs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Suppose I have executed this query in the nodejs app

```
var query ="INSERT INTO `Customers` set ?";

conn.query(query, DataSet,function(err,result)
{
    if(err)
    {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }else{
        console.log(result);

    }
});
```

If any error occurs in the execution of the query I want the error to be displayed on the client side, and if not the success message should be displayed.

So the main issue is how to send the error message of the executed query to the client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're in an express router method you use the `res` object to push results back to the web client. Perhaps something like this.

```
const express = require( 'express' );
const router  = express.Router();

router.get( '/', function( req, res, next ) {
   conn.query(query, DataSet,function(err, result) {
   if(err) {
        res.status( 500 ).json( { status: 500, message: err } );
    }
    else {
        res.status( 200 ).json( { status: 200, message: result } );
    }
  });
});
```

This example tosses back a JSON object with the message in it, and tosses back either 500 (server error) or 200 (success) status. You may need something else. You still use the `res` object.